# Why doesn't my program write the "feet" into the excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, list, web-scraping

I tried making a program that scraped the data off a height and weight chart and moved it into a file on excel. All the web-scraping works well but when it tries inserting the information into excel it only enters weight. Not sure what i'm doing wrong, any suggestions?

```
from lxml import html 
import requests 
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
weight = []
feet = []

def scrape():
    list1 = [] 
    user_website = "https://disabled-world.com/calculators-charts/height-weight.php" 
    page = requests.get(user_website) 
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 
    list2 = tree.xpath('//td/text()')
    
    for x in list2: 
        list_holder = x.split(" ") 
        for i in list_holder: 
            list1.append(i.lower()) 
    subs = "'" 
    feet = [i for i in list2 if subs in i] 
    print([s.strip('"') for s in feet]) 
    #print([s.replace('\', ') for s in feet]) 
    subs3 = "lb"
    pounds = [i for i in list2 if subs3 in i]
    
    y = 0
    amount = len(pounds)/2
    for x in range(1, int(amount)+1):
        weight.append(pounds[y])
        y += 2
    
    print(weight)

def excel():

    heightweight = wb.add_sheet('HeightWeight')

    x = 1
    y = 0
    amount = len(weight)
    for z in range(1, int(amount)+1):
        heightweight.write(x, 0, weight[y])
        
        x += 1
        y += 1
    print("Done")
    
    x = 1
    y = 0
    amount = len(feet)
    for z in range(1, int(amount)+1):
        heightweight.write(0, x, feet[y])
        
        x += 1
        y += 1
    print("Done")
    
    wb.save("heightweight.xls")

scrape()
excel()
```

Comment: The line `feet = [i for i in list2 if subs in i]` creates a local variable and does not modify the global `feet`.

Comment: A quick fix would be to do `feet.extend([i for i in list2 if subs in i])` but I'd prefer not having globals at all.